# how can i automatically generate a non id value in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring, annotations, sessionfactory

I am using hibernate annotations, spring, a sessionFactory and defining everything in a context.xml (like so..)

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>mypackage.model.Attributes</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.format_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

On my entity I have several properties, one being the id and another a string value "externalId" that I need to be automatically generated. (as an example it might be "dev_" followed by a 5 digit numerical value representing the id. so if the id is 4 then the externalId would be 'dev_00004')

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ATTRIBUTES")
public class Attributes {

    private Long id;
    private String externalId;
    ...
    ...


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column( name = "ID" )
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Long p_id ) {
        id = p_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "EXTERNALID")
    public String getExternalId() {
        return externalId;
    }
    public void setExternalId(String p_externalId) {
        externalId = p_externalId;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I had a look into the @PrePersist but all the dao's etc use saveOrUpdate and the two don't seem to go hand in hand.  I thought perhaps @preUpdate might work, but again that doesn't appear to get called.  Can anyone give me any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I had a look into the @PrePersist but all the dao's etc use saveOrUpdate and the two don't seem to go hand in hand. I thought perhaps @PreUpdate might work, but again that doesn't appear to get called.

PrePersist/PreUpdate are JPA annotations so for them to work, you will have to use an EntityManager.

> Can anyone give me any ideas on how I might achieve this?

Use the "equivalent" from Hibernate Core i.e. an interceptor or the event system.

#### Reference

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [Chapter 12. Interceptors and events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
public void setId( Long p_id ) {
        id = p_id;
        this.externalId = "dev_" + StringUtils.leftPad(p_id.toString(), 5, '0') );
    }
```

?

String utils from http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [PreInsertEventListener](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.2.2.ga/hibernate-3.2.2.ga-javadoc.jar!/org/hibernate/event/PreInsertEventListener.html) and hook it into your SessionFactory.  Then implement the listener to watch for this particular object type and allocate your external ID as necessary.

You initialise the event listeners using a map property of the spring factory bean.

```
  <property name="eventListeners" ref="hibernateEventListenerMap">

  <util:map id="hibernateEventListenerMap">
    <entry key="pre-insert">
      <list>
        <ref bean="customEventListenerBeanNameHere"/>
      </list>
    </entry>
  </util:map>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful - just looking into it now :-)